# how to show queried user first name in the trigger email body

Tags: trigger

in my current trigger I need to send email to customer with some body. Everything is fine with the following code(actually there is a lot code snippet but am specifying only current context code snippet), my requirement is how to put the queried user first name into the body?. Any one having any idea. Thanks in Advance guys.

```
User u = [SELECT Id,FirstName,LastName FROM User WHERE Id= :UserInfo.getUserId()] ;
 Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();  
            mail.setToAddresses(new List<String>{cs.ContactEmail}); 
            mail.setSubject('Your current Sales');
            String body = 'Hello from Amazon Stores';
            body += 'Thank you for sending the request for sales details';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
String body = 'Hello ' + u.FirstName + 'from Amazon Stores';
```

You can concatenate your query results with the body string and then use `mail.plainTextBody  = body;` to set the email body.